# Rails + ActiveAdmin: no success with custom instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, activeadmin, instance-variables

I'm trying to use the `controller` method in ActiveAdmin to no avail.

```
# ActiveAdmin.register Job do
controller do 
  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    @psr = @job.psr
  end
end

...

show do |job|
  attributes_table_for @psr do 
    row :created_at
  end
end
```

The above results in a `NilClass` error on `@psr`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variales are not shared to the `show` block, you need to do this:

```
show do |job|
  attributes_table_for job.psr do 
    row :created_at
  end
end
```